# Silverlight SSL and WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, iis, webserver

I have recently modified my web service in IIS7 to use SSL. To do this, I have created a self signed certificate and applied that to my web service. I then added https bindings to my site in IIS. I have changed my clientaccesspolicy.xml file to allow https ->

```
 <domain uri="https://*" />
```

Whenever I try to call my service from my SL site I get the following error:

> {System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Security error.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(Object sendState)}

Does anyone know what else I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: Is the certificate you are using a trusted certificate for the domain name you are accessing?

Comment: Hi @Chris. Sorry, I'm very new to web services and the like, how do would I check that?

Comment: @Ben, when you browse to the `HTTPS://` url in IE do you get a certificate error? If you do then the certificate is not trusted or there is some other error. The browser gives you the option to ignore the error, but this could be a problem for your web services.

Comment: @Ben, see if this link helps you along: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/markmann/archive/2009/10/05/silverlight-https-and-certificates.aspx

Comment: @Chris, No it's not. How do I make it trusted?

Comment: @Ben, The link I provided above explains how to trust a self signed certificate.